# New customizable toolbar crashes on Catalyst

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I have been playing around with the new toolbar in SwiftUI but it looks like it has some issues with the Catalyst (iPad works fine). Does anyone else experience the same issue?
Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            Text("1")
            Text("2")
            Text("3")
            Text("4")
            Text("5")
        }.toolbar(id: "ytuj") {
            
            ToolbarItem(id: "1", placement: .primaryAction) {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(id: "2", placement: .primaryAction) {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(id: "3", placement: .secondaryAction) {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(id: "4", placement: .secondaryAction, showsByDefault: false) {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            }
            
        }.toolbarRole(.editor)
     
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
   }
}
```

If you run this on a Catalyst it crashes when trying to customize the toolbar. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

**EDIT**: here's the error of the crash which is super-weird! This is just a simple "hello-world" app...

> *** Assertion failure in -[NSPasteboardItem setPropertyList:forType:], NSPasteboardItem.m:210

Comment: seems to work well for me, on macos 13 Ventura, using xcode 14.1-beta, target macCatalyst IOS-16.0. It may be different on other systems.

Comment: Same hardware / software configuration for me and it crashes. (Intel Mac)

Comment: ok, my mistake. I had another look. All works if I just click on the buttons in the popup, but crashes if I drag the "heart".

Comment: yeah.. sorry. perhaps my description was not very clear. It crashes when you try to drag any item into the toolbar. And dragging items from the toolbar to the editor, seem to just drag the whole window...